# Get the field name of a class without hardcoding

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic model class like this

```
class User(BaseModel):
   username: str
   firstname: str
   lastname: str
```

Now, I want to be able to reference "username" without hardcoding (like how I was able to reference the class name)

```
setup_index(User.__name__, "username")
```

Is there any way without going through the code generation route ?

Comment: Something like `getattr(User, "username")`?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `getattr` and the `setattr` function to directly access attributes from classes

```
 user = User('Vegeta') #initializing a class instance with username 'Vegeta'
 new_username = getattr(user, 'username') #getting the attribute and assigning it

 setup_index(User.__name__, new_username)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If the client knows the name of the member, then `getattr(user, 'username')` can be used (as mentioned by @michael-butscher).
2. If the client does not know the name of the member, then a getter function can be created via `name_getter = operator.attrgetter('username')` and provided to the client to be used as `name_getter(user)`.  The same effect can be achieved by defining a getter method in `User` and providing a reference to this method.  Either ways, if `username` is an implementation detail, then this approach helps hide such details from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but you could also do either one of the following (with some negligible performance sacrifice):

```py
user = User(username="JohnAppleseed", firstname="John", lastname="Appleseed")

# method one, pydantic not used
username = user.__dict__.get('username')

# method two, no encoders called
username = user.dict().get('username')

# method three, encoders called
import json
username = json.loads(user.json()).get('username')
```

This avoids the call to `getattr`, which in my opinion is not very elegant